# How come that primary member behind secondary in one mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

On our production environment we have strange behavior of a mongo replica, our primary is always behind secondaries.

***rs.status()**:*

```
{
    "set" : "repl01",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:28.000Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "syncingTo" : "prodsrv04:27018",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "prodsrv02:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 6271,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1392894670, 97),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:10.000Z"),
            "self" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "prodsrv03:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 6270,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1392894670, 68),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:10.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:28.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "prodsrv04:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 6270,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1392894669, 113),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:09.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:27.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-02-20T11:11:28.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : 6
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

- Master optime: Timestamp(1392894669, 113);
- Slave optime : Timestamp(1392894670, 68);

How come?

Comment: Is it because you have called rs.status() from the secondary and there is a little bit of lag to primary? There's also something odd with the lastHeartbeatRecv time on the other secondary..

Comment: Yeah. Whoa. Is the **time** in sync on all machines?

Comment: Neil Lunn - they use one ntp server, but have different time, difference is 21 sec.

Comment: John Greenall - lastHeartbeatRecv changes between 1970 and normal time. We have invoked rs.status() from master and secondaries and had same picture.

Comment: @user854301 Use the '@' in the comments responses if you expect the person who commented to get your comment and answer. And your ntp sync is **not**working properly if there is any difference at all. + Look into the '1970' date. It's a real problem